# C# 3.5 Adobe Interop Version 10 Printing Preferences

Tags: c#, printing, acrobat

Is there any way to set printing preferences in Adobe Acrobat 10 programatically before printing a document?

I need to be able to specify auto portrait/landscape, print on both sides of paper, flip on short side, and actual size preferences.

I notice there is a method for the Acrobat.AcroApp object called SetPreference(), but have been unable to find a listing of what the preference codes/values are...

I can get the document to print, I just need to get printer settings set before I print. For anyone interested the code goes something like this....

```
var acrobatApplication = new Acrobat.AcroApp();
var acrobatDocument = new Acrobat.AcroAVDoc();

acrobatDocument.Open("c:\\temp\\testdoc.pdf", "test.pdf");

var acrobatPdfDocument = (Acrobat.AcroPDDoc)acrobatDocument.GetPDDoc();

var totalPageCount = acrobatPdfDocument.GetNumPages();
var lastPageNumber = totalPageCount - 1;

var printResult = acrobatDocument.PrintPagesSilent(0, lastPageNumber, 3, 0, 1);

acrobatApplication.CloseAllDocs();
acrobatApplication.Exit();
```

Details: visual studio 2008, win xp, C# 3.5, Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library.

Any help would be appreciated!